# Linux man page for socket does not define PF_PACKET domain

Tags: linux, sockets, manpage

The [Linux man page for socket()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) does not appear to mention or define the PF_PACKET domain option. It lists only the AF_ domains.

Is the documentation just incomplete, obsolete or is there some specific reason why raw socket domains are not mentioned?

Comment: Read the **NOTES** section of the man page, it explains why packet families aren't documented.